# How to configure webpack 5 to bundle the module Web Worker script correctly which imports other modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, web-worker

As per the documentation, I am not using `worker-loader`, I am trying to use the native way suggested by the [webpack-5 documentation](https://webpack.js.org/guides/web-workers/).

Below is the **usage of the worker script** in the main thread.

```js
const worker = new window.Worker(
    new URL("../workers/listOperation.worker.js", import.meta.url),
    {
        type: "module",
    },
);
worker.postMessage({ list: hugeList, params: reqData });
worker.onerror = err => console.error(err);
worker.onmessage = e => {
    const { list } = e.data;
    // Usage of `list` from the response
    worker.terminate();
};
return worker;
```

*It works fine if there are no imports used in the script. But when I import any node modules (e.g. `loadash/get`) or any other function/constants from local, it does not work as the output webWorker bundle file doesn't transpile and bundle the imported code. It keeps the "import" statement as it is.*

Below is the worker script (`listOperation.worker.js`)

```js
import get from "lodash/get";
import { ANY_CONSTANT } from "../constants"; // This is some local constant

addEventListener("message", e => {
    const { list, params } = e.data;
    
    // Here I have some usage of `get` method from `lodash/get` and ANY_CONSTANT
    
    self.postMessage({
        list: list,
    });
});
```

Webpack outputs the bundle file like below which won't be usable by the browser, if I put the `/\.worker.js$/` pattern in the the `exclude` of `babel-loader` rule.

```js
import get from "lodash/get";import{ANY_CONSTANT}from"../constants";addEventListener("message",(e=>{const{list:s,params:t,.......
```

And even if I don't put the `/\.worker.js$/` pattern in the the `exclude` of `babel-loader` rule, the output bundle still doesn't include the implementation of `get` from `lodash/get` or the value of the constant. It just outputs it in cjs using `require`.

Also, I made use of asset module so that I can put the output file inside a directory, not directly in the root of the `dist` folder. Configuration changes in my webpack.config looks like this.

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {...},
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/(node_modules)/, /\.worker.js$/],
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader", // This uses the config defined in babel.config.js
                },
            },
            {
                test: /\.worker.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                type: "asset/resource",
                generator: {
                    filename: "js/workers/[hash][ext][query]",
                },
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Comment: Github repo to replicate the same issue can be found here - https://github.com/debo07/WebWorkerPOC/tree/a22ee78ea65ff81bbb0f2f13f56978cdfa644c0c